# Reactive form duplicate code

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material2, reactive

I'm using reactive form and I have two forms login and registration.
Registration:

```
<div class="registration_wrap">
   <div class="registration">
      <form [formGroup]="form"
            novalidate>

         <h2>Registration</h2>

         <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <input matInput
                   placeholder="Username"
                   name="username"
                   [formControlName]="'username'">

            <mat-error *ngIf="form.controls['username'].invalid">{{ 
       getErrorMessage('username') }}</mat-error>
         </mat-form-field>

         <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <input matInput
                   placeholder="Email"
                   name="email"
                   [formControlName]="'email'">
            <mat-error *ngIf="form.controls['email'].invalid">{{ 
        getErrorMessage('email') }}</mat-error>
         </mat-form-field>

         <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <input matInput
                   placeholder="Enter your password"
                   [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'"
                   name="password"
                   [formControlName]="'password'">
            <mat-icon matSuffix
                      (click)="hide = !hide"
                      class="eye">
               {{hide ? 'visibility' : 'visibility_off'}}
            </mat-icon>
            <mat-error *ngIf="form.controls['password'].invalid">{{ 
      getErrorMessage('password') }}</mat-error>
         </mat-form-field>

         <ng2-password-strength-bar
                 [passwordToCheck]="form.controls['password'].value"
                 [barLabel]="barLabel"
                 [barColors]="myColors">
         </ng2-password-strength-bar>

         <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <input matInput
                   placeholder="Duplicate password"
                   [type]="hide1 ? 'password' : 'text'"
                   name="duplicate"
                   [formControlName]="'duplicate'">
            <mat-icon matSuffix
                      (click)="hide1 = !hide1"
                      class="eye">
               {{hide1 ? 'visibility' : 'visibility_off'}}
            </mat-icon>
            <mat-error *ngIf="form.controls['duplicate'].invalid">{{ 
    getErrorMessage('duplicate') }}</mat-error>
         </mat-form-field>

         <mat-checkbox
                 [formControlName]="'checkbox'"
         >Check me!
         </mat-checkbox>

         <div class="but_wrap">
            <button mat-fab color="primary"
                    (click)="onSubmit(form)"
                    [disabled]="form.invalid">
               <mat-icon>done</mat-icon>
            </button>
            <button mat-fab color="accent"
                    [routerLink]="'/login'">
               <mat-icon>reply</mat-icon>
            </button>
         </div>
         <!--<p>Form value: {{ form.value | json }}</p>-->
         <!--<p>Form status: {{ form.status | json }}</p>-->
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

Login:

```
 <div class="login_wrap">
  <div class="login">
    <form [formGroup]="form"
          novalidate>

      <h2>Login</h2>

      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input matInput
               placeholder="Username"
               name="username"
               [formControlName]="'username'">
        <mat-error *ngIf="form.controls['username'].invalid">{{ 
    getErrorMessage('username') }}</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input matInput
               placeholder="Enter your password"
               [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'"
               name="password"
               [formControlName]="'password'">
        <mat-icon matSuffix
                  (click)="hide = !hide"
                  class="eye">
          {{hide ? 'visibility' : 'visibility_off'}}
        </mat-icon>
        <mat-error *ngIf="form.controls['password'].invalid">{{ 
    getErrorMessage('password') }}</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>

      <div class="but_wrap">
        <button mat-fab color="primary"
                (click)="onSubmit(form)"
                [disabled]="form.invalid">
          <mat-icon>keyboard_backspace</mat-icon>
        </button>

        <button mat-fab color="accent"
                [routerLink]="'/registration'">
          <mat-icon>group</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </div>

      <!--<p>Form value: {{ form.value | json }}</p>-->
      <!--<p>Form status: {{ form.status | json }}</p>-->
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see both forms have duplicate code

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input matInput
               placeholder="Username"
               name="username"
               [formControlName]="'username'">

        <mat-error *ngIf="form.controls['username'].invalid">{{ 
    getErrorMessage('username') }}</mat-error>
     </mat-form-field>
```

And I want to know can I use component or something where I can put this code and return it in my HTML template. I know I can do that with simple component, but I use reactive forms. Or I should leave it as it is? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you have exactly same fields, it can be very easily achieved with a child component, let's say `child-component`. And if you have same fields, I would certainly recommend to use a separate component, after all, we all want to be as DRY as possible, right? :)

So create a child component, you add that tag in your parent template and pass a nested group (or the whole form) to that child component, treat it no different as a form that would be in a single component.

Sample...

Parent TS:

```ts
myForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.myForm = fb.group({ 
    someField: [''],
    nestedGroup: fb.group({
      someOtherField: ['']
    });
  })
}
```

Parent html:

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <input formControlName="someField" >
  <child-component [nestedGroup]="myForm.controls.nestedGroup"></child-component>
</form>
```

Then just use `@Input` in your child to catch the nested group, mark it as a formgroup and insert your fields with form controls inside that form group.

TS:

```ts
@Input() nestedGroup: FormGroup;
```

Html:

```html
<div [formGroup]="nestedGroup">
  <input formControlName="someOtherField">
</div>
```

And since this the formgroup is an object and objects are mutable in JS, no need to use `@Output`, your parent will beware of what is going on in the child :)